# Ubuntu crash: BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference

Tags: kernel

Since sunday my ubuntu server has crashed two times. For the second one I found this error message

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference
mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
 at 0000000000000038
IP: pick_next_entity+0x11/0x120
PGD 80000007f9939067 P4D 80000007f9939067 PUD 7f9504067 PMD 0
Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
Modules linked in: intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic i915 irqbypass drm_
CPU: 0 PID: 2231 Comm: mysqld Not tainted 4.15.0-123-generic #126-Ubuntu
Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/P8H77-M PRO, BIOS 9012 09/18/2018
RIP: 0010:pick_next_entity+0x11/0x120
RSP: 0018:ffffc23ac9857df0 EFLAGS: 00010046
RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: ffff9cef1fa00000
RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
RBP: ffffc23ac9857e08 R08: 0000000000000004 R09: 0000000000021080
R10: ffffc23ac9857e60 R11: 00016ba0372bae8e R12: 0000000000000000
R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff9ceef3b0b7c8 R15: ffffc23ac9857ec0
FS:  00007fcb5dffb700(0000) GS:ffff9cef1fa00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
CR2: 0000000000000038 CR3: 00000007f9bea004 CR4: 00000000001606f0
Call Trace:
pick_next_task_fair+0x7b/0x5a0
 ? __schedule+0x11e/0x880
 ? schedule+0x2c/0x80
 ? sys_sched_yield+0x5c/0x70
 ? do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
 ? entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x41/0xa6
Code: c7 be 00 00 10 00 e8 bf ec ff ff eb e2 b8 ff ff ff ff eb e4 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 41 55 41 54 49 89 fc 53 <48> 8b 7f 38 48 89 f3 4d 8b 6c 24 58
RIP: pick_next_entity+0x11/0x120 RSP: ffffc23ac9857df0
```

I havn't installed new packages or started some of my code. It happends when the server is idle.

Comment: Do you have `thermald` installed? Have you written your own configuration file for it?

Comment: @heynnema No I dont. Neigther installed or made a custom config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hosting company did a hard drive test and found a malfunctioning hard drive. They replaced the hard drive and I haven't had any crashes since.

Unfortunately, I do not know the test procedure that the hosting company has used.

The UEFI ("BIOS") did not cause the error. My hosting company (Hetzner, in this case) just uses a customized UEFI ("BIOS") that follows a different versioning.

tldr: hard drive malfunctioning, replaced it, works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

**BIOS**

ASUS P8H77-M PRO

It's possible that you have an incorrect BIOS installed.

You have BIOS version 9012, dated 09/18/2018.

The most current BIOS that I see on the web site is 1505, dated 03/20/2015, and can be [seen and downloaded here](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/P8H77M_PRO/HelpDesk_BIOS/).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your motherboard.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**memory**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.